# In D3 v4, how do I keep the width of a bar centered around a tick mark?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3 v4 (most, if not all, of the examples out there are for v3).  Back in v3, they had something called rangeBand() which would be able to dynamically position everything neatly on the x-axis for me.

Now, in v4, I am wondering how to do that.

I have a bar chart:

```
var barEnter = vis.selectAll("g") 
                  .data(rawdata)
                  .enter()
                  .append('g')
                  .append("rect")
                  .attr("class", "bar")
                  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.key); })
                  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })   
                  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
                  .attr("width", canvas_width / rawdata.length);
```

It is the width of this bar this is messing me up.  If I set it to `canvas_width / rawdata.length`, it nicely positions the bars centered around each tick on the x-axis.  The problem is that all the bars are pressed together and there is no padding in between.

So, naturally, I tried to do `x.paddingInner(.5)` which does add some padding but now the bars are not centered around the tick marks.  Doing anything with `x.paddingOuter()` messes things up even more.

After searching around, I found that `rangeBand()` is what I want but that's only for v3.  In the v4 docs, there is nothing that quite looks like it.  Is it `rangeRound()`?  Is it `align()`?  I'm not sure.  If anyone can point me in the right direction, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing your code for the axis, I suppose you're using `scaleOrdinal()`. If that's the case, you can change for [`scaleBand()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleBand), in which it's very easy to center the bar around the tick.

All you need is:

- `band.paddingInner([padding])`: Sets the inner padding of the bars
- `band.bandwidth()`: Gives you the bandwidth of each bar.

Then, you set the `x` position using the corresponding variable in your data and the `width` using `bandwidth()`.

This is a small snippet to show you how it works:

```js
var w = 300, h = 100, padding = 20;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var data = [{name: "foo", value:50},
            {name: "bar", value:80},
            {name: "baz", value: 20}];

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0,w])
  .domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.name}))
  .paddingInner(0.2)
  .paddingOuter(0.2);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

var bars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect");

bars.attr("x", function(d){ return xScale(d.name)})
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("y", function(d){ return (h - padding) - d.value})
  .attr("height", function(d){ return d.value})
  .attr("fill", "teal");

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Geradro How could we apply max rect width when using xScale.bandwidth() ?